# How to combine 2 calenders from 2 different sharepoint online sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-calendar, json

I've received the assignement to combine 2 calenders from 2 different sharepointonline sites.

From what i researched, this is not possible with the out of the box overlay solution SharePoint has to offer so I went looking for an other way.

I stumbled upon the use of Javascript/JSON but as I have no experience in that matter I thought it would be advisable to ask my question here.
I've succeeded in using rest to fill in a calendar but only when that one is also in the domain, like making a new calendar in `XXX.sharepoint/calendar`, when the Original is also in the `XXX` name.
Now I need to find a way to get the calendar data from `YYY.sharepoint` and add these 2 togheter in a calender in the `XXX` site.

Anyone knows on how to complete this task?
All help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you add your code? Also, is this two different O365 tenants?

Comment: @wjervis, yes it's 2 different O365 tenants. The code I've used is a basic json to get data trough REST, nothing more. I've tried calling the other tenant this way aswell but that doesn't work, probably authentication and a whole other stuff blocking the way like this.

Comment: Yes, authentication will prevent that.  What you'll have to do is get an authorization token to the other tenant.  [This](http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/) link has details on how to do so.  If I had time, I would try to throw something together and write up an answer.

Comment: @wjervis Ty for linking this info, I tried several ways yesterday but none seemed to go succesfull. I tried to use the link you gave but ended up at an 403 error when trying to retrieve the digestcookie.

Also CORS seems not to be able in sharepoint online while this seems the way to go when having an on premise installation.

Comment: I tried it last night and got the same error.  Sorry it was no help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this before for merging two calendar but i know you can. Previously i used this technique to export calendar item from old calendar to a new one and it worked well.

Export both the calendar item to an excel file and merge those excel data. once all data cleansing is done import the excel file into the newly created calendar.

Note: if you find difficult to merge the items in the excel documents, you can import them into the SQL server and run some sql queries to do the job. once all done, export that to the excel file and import it into the SharePoint calendar.

Comment: If i did this once, the data keeps updated? Cause the calendar should be synced as much as possible, preferable less then a day difference with the original calendars

Comment: @Lschockaert this would only be a snapshot of the calendars at the moment it was created.

Comment: That's what i thought when I read it, ty for confirming this.

Comment: I dont think syncing will be possible. as @wjervis mentioned its just to move two calendar into one.